# Cannot set custom logging file path in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I use : Windows, java 8 (1.8.0_291), Spring boot v2.4.10.

I want to write my log messages in log file (and console). I configure my logger with **application.properties** (this file is located in the project resources folder):

```
#Try1 Don't work with it
# logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
#Try2 Don't work with it
# logging.level.ru.leodev=DEBUG

#Try3 Don't work with it
logging.level.root = DEBUG
logging.level.com.mycompany.stackexp = DEBUG
 
logging.pattern.console= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
 
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
 
logging.file=e:\Projects\logs\app.log
```

When my spring app starts, I write some test message in my log file, but I don't look my log file and record in it. I have folder **e:\Projects\logs**.

My spring class:

```
package com.mycompany.stackexp;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling 
@EnableAsync 
public class ThreadSpringServer { 
    
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context; //Config spring app
    
    public ThreadSpringServer(){}
    
    public void start() throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        
        Thread.currentThread().setName("ThreadSpringServer");
        
        System.out.println("Start SpringServer...");
        context = SpringApplication.run(ThreadSpringServer.class);
        System.out.println("SpringServer was successfully started, port: "+System.getProperty("server.port"));
        
    }
    
    @Bean("Bean1")
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        
        factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.parse("100MB"));
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.parse("100MB"));
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }   
}
```

And my spring controller class:

```
package com.mycompany.stackexp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext;

//my logger
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@RestController
public class ControllerSpring {
 
    private Logger springLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerSpring.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private ServletWebServerApplicationContext webServerAppCtxt;
    
    @GetMapping("/myLog")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSpringTestMes() throws InterruptedException, IOException, ParseException, Exception {
        springLogger.error("errorMes");
        springLogger.info("infoMes");
        springLogger.debug("debugMes");
        
        return "Spring boot create test mes in log file";
    }
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>AutoHandler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
       
        <!-- Spring for REST API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>     
       
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            
            <!-- Other build plugins for create .jar-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.10</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackexp.Main</mainClass>
                       
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                      
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackexp.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>AutoHandler</name>
</project>
```

I try to use my controller entity: "http://localhost:3333/myLog", and I expect the creation of a log file in my selected directory (path in application.properties): **e:\Projects\logs\app.log**, but there isn't log file in this directory.

When I do it, I look message in console, but I need my log file.
It turns out that spring not only does not write data to the file, but also does not create it at the specified path.

---

Can you tell me what my possible mistakes might be? When the program starts, no errors are displayed and everything starts as it should

Comment: First of all: your main application class must have a proper static main method. Check any tutorial for the correct way of defining it. Second: using System.out.println is not logging. It just writes something to console. Use proper logger.info method instead. Please try and update here any progress.

Comment: My answer: 1) I have a Main class. My ThreadSpringServer is located: Main.class/main/new Object of ThreadSpringServer.

The ThreadSpringServer class isn't the first main class for my app, it's some class.

2) I know that this line outputs  System.out.println data to the console. And I don't expect it to output data to a log file. I am waiting for the log file entry to be in the controller class in the getSpringTestMes method

Answer (score 0):

Try using `logback.xml` in your project :

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/app/logs/YOUR_FOLDER/YOUR_FILE.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>~/app/logs/YOUR_FOLDER/YOUR_FILE.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>400MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%thread] [%logger:%line] %msg%n
        </pattern>

    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] [%thread] [%logger:%line] %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="ir.co.pep" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" />
```

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

complete guild in below link:
[Logging in spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging)

Comment: When I try this, I have a error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/ElementSelector, can you help me?

Comment: Did you try mvn install command before run?

Comment: Yes, and I everything went well and without errors.

Comment: so your problem solved?

Comment: I can build my project, but when I use logback.xml I have error. Command "mvn install" doesnt' help me. 

I try to use application.properties. When I use it, I don't show message in console, and in my log file.

And I can't solve this problem, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I try mvn dependency tree:

[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile

Comment: I don't have:
ch.qos.logback:logback-core in spring boot web,

But i have it separately, in another dependency, apparently it affects, but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: so you have this dependency?

 <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I have ch.qos.logback v1.0.9, I do not know if I need to upgrade to your version.

<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

Comment: What do you think about it?

Comment: Check the existence of the dependency you added in your .m2 system file.

Comment: In directory: ".m2\repository\ch\qos\logback", I have logback-classic, logback-core, logback-parent. And I have my logback-classic\1.0.9 folder. Probably this library should be inside spring, and I have it outside spring, but still I do not know how to solve it

Comment: Do you have the jar file in the logback-classic\1.0.9 folder?

Comment: Yes, I have this folder

Comment: Not a folder, a jar file.

Comment: I have jar file

Comment: hmm..., try mvn clean for delete target folder and run project and check this path to be sure you have "ElementSelector" class :  ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi